# What is the best Regex for .htaccess to match anything except '?' or '/'

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have written a code in .htaccess file for search engine friendly URL purpose:

```
RewriteRule ^games/(.*\S)$ helper/Games.php?p=$1 [L]
```

As you see, anything after `games/` rewrites to `helper/Games.php?p=`

But I don't want `$_GET['p']` witch contains `?` or `/`.

For example below URLs should **NOT** be rewrites by my rule:

```
example.com/games/Test?Test
example.com/games/Test/Test
```

Please guide me to find correct Regex.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match against empty QUERY_STRING before rewriting the url:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^test/([^/]+)$ helper/Gampes.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to negate the set of values you don't want rather than using the wildcard `.`. So:

`RewriteRule ^games/([^/]*[^\s/])$ helper/Games.php?p=$1 [L]`

Since the query string isn't part of the match, you'll want to first:

`RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$`

Comment: Tnx. It work's fine for slash. But still rewrites `example.com/games/Test?Test` :(

Comment: I don't recall off the top of my head how Apache's regular expression parser works, but I would have expected this to be okay! Anyway, try sticking a backslash `\\` before the question marks.

Comment: ? is not part of match in RewriteRule's pattern. You have no option to remove it unless you use a RewriteCond.

Comment: How? Do you know? @starkeen

Comment: Good idea. Thank's. @starkeen